# Error connecting to remote DB with Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For my project I am trying to make a connection to a remote database with Rails 4.

I modified the `database.yml` file and it looks so:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: false
  encoding: utf8
  database: <name_DB>
  username: <user_DB>
  password: <pass_DB>
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3307
  pool: 5
```

I got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
  timeout: 5000
```

-I don't have any model until now.

-gem 'mysql2' already installed

-A connection through SSH works and also with MySQL workbench.

Am I missing something? How can I achieve the connection? Should I modify something else?

Comment: Only two things I can think of - triple check your configuration and check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` on your remote server.  Of course, check remote server firewall settings as well.

Comment: In etc/hosts.deny looks like : # ALL: PARANOID. Is that ok?

Comment: Any line which begins with a '#' is a comment and ignored.  If you have checked your configuration, I would look at the answer linked to by @Yury.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution.

Important for the connection to work.

1. Create SSH with the remote server!! `SSH -L 3307:mysql:3306 <server_name>` `-p6060`
2. Configure your `database.yml` as posted in the original question.
3. Done.

Comment: What do you mean with OP?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect to your DB with the ssh tunnel, it wouldn't work.

You need to make your mysql server accessible for remote connections:

[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)